# Trying to access Hash from Method, but keep getting NameError

Tags: ruby, methods, hash

I'm a Rubywan, so I'm still new to this. Any advice would be extremely helpful! Currently working on figuring out methods and hashes. I'm trying to access the Hash named school, but keep coming up with a NameError.  More specifically, this is the error (followed by the method that's trying to access the Hash):

```
test.rb:19:in `student_grade': undefined local variable or method `school' for main:Object (NameError).

def student_grade(student_name)
  student = school[:students].select do |student| 
    if student[:name] == student_name 
      student_grade = student[:grade]
      puts student_grade 
    else 
      puts "Student doesn't exist!"
    end 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`school` local variable is created outside the scope of your method(method has its own scope of local variables). Thus you can't access that inside the method `student_grade`. As an example see below:

```
hsh = {:a => 1}
def foo
  hsh
end
foo 
# undefined local variable or method `hsh' for main:Object (NameError)
```

To access that you have to pass it as below:

```
hsh = {:a => 1}
def foo(hsh)
  hsh
end
foo(hsh) # => {:a=>1}
```

To read more about the scope of local variables see here : [**`Scope of local variable`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/localvars.html)

Comment: It is possible that OP is writing a simple class and could use an instance variable `@school`